# Which RESTful route to use when updating an item involves creating and adding a new item to it?

Tags: node.js, rest, post, routes, put

New to coding and had a question about structure of routes rather than actual coding. I'll use the example of a libraries and books web app below to clarify my question.

I want to create a new library:
POST libraries route.

I want to update the library name:
PUT libraries/libraryId route.

I want to create a new book.
POST books

I want to update the book name.
PUT books/bookId

I am viewing a list of books in a library in my single page app. There is a form to add a new book to the library.

Which route should the form go to in line with RESTful routing or it doesn't matter?

1. Form posts to the new book route and then updates library:
   POST /books/libraryId

or

2. The form PUTs to the update library route and creates a new book within that route:
   PUT /library/libraryId/newbookname

EDIT: Some clarifications based on comments below.. 
So in my scenario, new books can be created outside of a library by users but they cannot allocate to a library. The librarian administrates the library so can create new books which would automatically be added to their library.

Comment: if your app doesn't allow adding books seperatly and you can add a new book only within a library then it doesn't make sense to have two seperate endpoints (POST+PUT). You can do that with one API call which in my opinion will follow this order : create a new book --> add it to the appropriate library : if a problem occured while adding the book to the library --> the new created book must be deleted to avoid confusion.
In case you can add books seperatly and then assign them to libraries then you follow the same steps : add a book --> assign to library

Comment: Sorry hadn't finished my edit before the timeout. So in my scenario, new books can be created outside of a library by users but they cannot allocate to a library. The librarian administrates the library so can create new books which would automatically be added to their library. Does that change your view?

Comment: It really depends on your database structure and how your app is designed. You can do it both ways as you described. Still in my opinion you will have to create the new book and only if that call was successful you will call your update library root with the new created book id to update your library. So you will have at the end of the day two separate endpoints and you will call them one after the other (POST <create book> --> PUT <update library>)

Comment: That's helpful. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if the books are related to a library then you will have a route like that to create a book: POST `/libraries/libraryId/books`, and to update a book: PUT `/libraries/libraryId/books/bookId`.

Also make sure to respect these basic rules about HTTP methods: https://nordicapis.com/understanding-idempotency-and-safety-in-api-design/

POST are not always for create and PUT for updates.

Comment: Thanks for that. In my situation, there would be new books created by users that aren't related to a library.

New books can be created by the librarian that are automatically associated with their library but can also become unlinked to that library.

Comment: ok so maybe just one POST `/books` and in the body sometimes a given libraryId and in the update you can also pass a libraryId to update it

Answer (score 1):

The choice of target-uri primarily depends on which currently cached resource you want to automatically invalidate.  See [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4).

For instance, consider this protocol: you `GET /libraries/123`, and observe in the representation that a book is missing.  So you then get the form to add the book to the library, and submit it.  Where should that submission go?

Well, the currently cached representation of `/libraries/123` doesn't have that book, so if we want the user to be able to verify that things changed, then they are going to need a new copy of `/libraries/123` to look at, so we should invalidate the currently cached copy by submitting the post request to `/libraries/123`

Note that this is the same target-uri that we use when trying to update that library name.  That's deliberate.

A good heuristic to consider is "how would you do this on the web?".  When we are using HTML to navigate a domain application protocol, `POST` is the only unsafe method we have available.  So adding a new book and changing the name would both be `POST` requests -- in other words, the `POST` handler may need to look at the body of the request to figure out what to do.

Comment: That's really helpful, thanks. So are you saying it would be more appropriate to have a PUT /libraries/123 route and use a form with a body that contains a new book flag and data rather than a new books route which subsequently updates the library?